# Radio app For Android

Tags: java, android, fm-radio

Am trying to develop Android application for radio app without streaming process. which means i would like to bring all fm frequency into my app where users can search frequency and can listen to their fav radio. so is it possible to bring radio app into my app

Answer (score 0):

The "radio" on a phone is not the same as "broadcast radio" or what most people simply refer to as "radio". Radio is band of frequencies that is regulated by different nations for different purposes. Cellular "radio" is actually a similar band as UHF TV, WiFi and Bluetooth (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_frequencies) These are 800MHz to about 5 GHz.

AM/FM Radio frequencies are not even close.

FM operates at about 60-90MHz (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_broadcasting)

AM operates at about 150 - 1600 kHz or 0.15 - 1.6 MHz (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM_broadcasting) although "short wave radio" operates at lightly higher frequencies.

In other words, the "radio" on an Android device (or cellular phone) doesn't detect the "radio" that you tune into with a car or home stereo/radio system. They both use a form of light called "radio" but it's like using blue shaded glasses to see red light - it doesn't work. (Like the old 3D glasses, they are colored so you can only see certain wavelengths.)